# is there memory leak if we don't delete memory and the application has exited

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I write a piece of test code in VS2005 like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Base {
public:
    Base() {printf("Base +\n");};
    ~Base() {printf("Base -\n");};
    char val[1024 * 1024 * 100];
};

void main()
{
    Base *p = new Base();
    return;
}
```

build, open a cmd window, then execute this console application.
open windows task manager to watch memory usage status.

I find two things:
1 the destructor is not called;
2 there is no memory leak from the windows task manager result.

is memory deleted by C++ runtime, or is it deleted by OS when the process exit? I just wonder the details about what happens to 100MB meory allocated in contructor after the main() return. If someone can tell me it is appreciated, and thanks.

Answer (score 3):

After your program exits, the operating system will reclaim all used memory, whether or not delete has been called on it.

Other resources, like sockets, might take longer to be released by the operating system, but will eventually be reclaimed.

Comment: so, it totally depends on the OS to do the reclaim? I wonder whether the C++ runtime can do any help on this, just like it will call destructors for global variables, is it smart enough to do the same thing for heap objects.

Comment: It's the job of the operating system. The C++ runtime won't call functions that you don't tell it to call, and in this case, you didn't tell it to call the destructor on that memory.

Answer (score 1):

It will be up to the operating system.

However, things that you thought would go away when the app goes away tend to stay in memory longer than you thought. At some point, the code in main is moved to some function that gets called once. And then that function gets called multiple times. And then you have a leak. Better coding defensively in the first place than to fix problems later. Maybe years later.

Answer (score 0):

**Destructor** not get called because you are not deleting your **class B** pointer.
Also after your application exits all the allocated resources get released irrespective whether you released it or not.

Answer (score 0):

As with other answer, it's up to the operating system.

Having said this, it's usually well documented what will be clean up upon program termination.

This usually include application's private memory, files, sockets, resource handles, GUI resources, and may exclude resources that is global or shared amount many applications. (e.g. POSIX shared memory will persist until reboot if you do not call `shm_unlink`).